# I got Execution failed for task ':app:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]' while building my react native app

Tags: android, react-native, cmake, metro-bundler

The app was working fine yesterday, but now it gives me this error :

```
Execution failed for task ':app:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.
> [CXX1429] error when building with cmake using C:\{my path}\node_modules\react-native\ReactAndroid\cmake-utils\default-app-setup\CMakeLists.txt: -- The C compiler identification is Clang 14.0.6
  -- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 14.0.6
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
  -- Check for working C compiler: C:/{my path}/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe - skipped
  -- Detecting C compile features
  -- Detecting C compile features - done
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/{my path}/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++.exe - skipped
  -- Detecting CXX compile features
  -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/{my path}/android/app/.cxx/Debug/5o3yy2s5/arm64-v8a/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

......
  CMake Error at C:{my path}/app/build/generated/rncli/src/main/jni/Android-rncli.cmake:6 (add_subdirectory):
    add_subdirectory called with incorrect number of arguments
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    C:{my path}/node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/cmake-utils/ReactNative-application.cmake:123 (include)
    CMakeLists.txt:31 (include)


  CMake Error at C:{my path}/PFE-AssistiveBanking-RN/android/app/build/generated/rncli/src/main/jni/Android-rncli.cmake:7 (add_subdirectory):
    add_subdirectory called with incorrect number of arguments
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    C:{my path}/node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/cmake-utils/ReactNative-application.cmake:123 (include)
    CMakeLists.txt:31 (include)


  CMake Error at C:{my path}/android/app/build/generated/rncli/src/main/jni/Android-rncli.cmake:8 (add_subdirectory):
    add_subdirectory called with incorrect number of arguments
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    C:{my path}/node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/cmake-utils/ReactNative-application.cmake:123 (include)
    CMakeLists.txt:31 (include)


  CMake Error at C:{my path}/android/app/build/generated/rncli/src/main/jni/Android-rncli.cmake:9 (add_subdirectory):
    add_subdirectory called with incorrect number of arguments
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    C:{my path}/node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/cmake-utils/ReactNative-application.cmake:123 (include)
    CMakeLists.txt:31 (include)


  CMake Error at C:{my path}/android/app/build/generated/rncli/src/main/jni/Android-rncli.cmake:10 (add_subdirectory):        
    add_subdirectory called with incorrect number of arguments
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    C:{my path}/node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/cmake-utils/ReactNative-application.cmake:123 (include)
    CMakeLists.txt:31 (include)


  CMake Error at C:{my path}/android/app/build/generated/rncli/src/main/jni/Android-rncli.cmake:11 (add_subdirectory):        
    add_subdirectory called with incorrect number of arguments
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    C:{my path}/node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/cmake-utils/ReactNative-application.cmake:123 (include)
    CMakeLists.txt:31 (include)


  CMake Error at C:/{my path}/node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/cmake-utils/ReactNative-application.cmake:126 (target_link_libraries):
    Cannot specify link libraries for target
    "react_codegen_RNDateTimePickerCGen" which is not built by this project.
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    CMakeLists.txt:31 (include)
```

Has anyone encountered this and found how to fix the issue, I am in dire help

I tried using `yarn start --reset-cache` and `.\gradlew clean` , i also tried degrading the cmake version from android studio but it didn't work, to top it off when the emulator runs for the first time , it opens many consecutive android error dialogues
[android emulator error dialogue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vIrI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Since I have finally fixed it, it took me a little bit, and i am not sure if i fixed it fully but here's what i did:

1. deleted the older AVD i have and made a new one.
2. in my project directory, i deleted the /.gradle and the /.idea (kept a back up of this one just in case).
3. navigated to /.gradle directory in my user directory and deleted , caches, daemon and wrapper folders.
4. under the same user directory i navigated to /.android and deleted , cache.
5. restarted my pc
6. lastly, reopened my project , in the terminal: cd android
   and then ./gradlew assembleRelease.
   and when i ran it, it worked but there's still some issues in another project for some reason.