Execution failed for task ':app:buildCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a] in reactnative
After I install the needed libraries for react-native navigation, following this docs https://reactnative.dev/docs/navigation , i get this error Execution failed for task ':app:buildCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a], and idk how to fix it
I´ve tried everything nothing works

Duplicated question. I think this is what you need. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78244859/i-got-execution-failed-for-task-appconfigurecmakedebugarm64-v8a-while-buil/79219605#79219605
